# Shared Preferences in Android applications

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm having a small understanding problem. I have an Android app which uses shared preferences to store data. To get this I use:

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(prefs, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

My problem is when this method gets called on other android devices where the app is newly installed, is there no shared preference file?

My other question is what will happen with this file when I uninstall the app on my phone?

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't set any preferences it will create a new file.  If you uninstall the app it removes the preferences as well.  If you update the app they stay.

Answer (score 2):

SharedPreferences are stored locally on your device and are not synced with your Google account by default. 
SharedPreferences get deleted when you uninstall the app.

Take a look at my blogpost: http://mikebdev.blogspot.de/2013/05/sharedpreferences-basics.html